# cabal, module and dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was wondering, when you download and install a package via cabal, does cabal tries to build everything or only what you need.
For example lots of package include and HaskellTemplate module which obviously requires the HaskellTemplate extension. What happend if you use a compiler which doesn't support this extension, but don't care about this module because you are not using it anyway ?

Comment: When a project gets compiled, every file in the project that is an exported module or is a dependency of an exported module gets compiled.  If a compiler, e.g. Hugs, does not support a newer extension like `TypedHoles` then the compilation will fail.

Comment: Ok, it's better to put, for example an 'th' module  in totally separate package then.

Comment: You could also look at [conditional compilation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal/Developer-FAQ#Conditional_compilation) (more info [here](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#meaning-of-field-values-when-using-conditionals)) that would allow you to just keep them in different modules and conditionally export specific ones based on which compiler is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `cabal install` a package from hackage, cabal needs to install all the dependencies of that package too.

Usually, all files in a package get compiled. However, there are a few exceptions:

1. Cabal by default doesn't build test-suites or benchmarks.
2. If the package has flags, some modules might be disabled if certain flags are set/unset. There can be dependencies which are guarded by a flag, and cabal will automatically try to disable/enable the flag if it cannot satisfy dependencies with the flag enabled.

To illustrate point 2, consider the following package definition:

```
name: foo
version: 0.1

flag withGHC
  default: True
  manual: False # Allow cabal to figure out the correct value for the flag automatically   

library
  exposed-modules:
    Foo.Bar # This will always be compiled
  if flag(withGHC)
    build-depends: ghc
    exposed-modules:
      Foo.GHC  # This will only be compiled when withGHC is True
```

Now, when you install `foo` under GHC, cabal will find that it can satsify the dependencies even with the flag enabled, so `Foo.GHC` will be built.

But if you try to install `foo` with another compiler, cabal will see that when chosing `withGHC = True`, this leads to the dependency `ghc`, which it cannot satisfy. Thus, it will chose `withGHC = False`, and `Foo.GHC` will not be built.

Comment: I didn't realize that cabal could *decide* which flag to use. Is there a way then to build something only if a dependency is present but without installing if not (even though it could be done in finite amount of time)